# Netplan - Bridging over a bond on Ubuntu 18.04 KVM host

Tags: networking, server, kvm-virtualization, netplan

Sorry in advance for the long post, this has been rattling me days.

I've got a server with 4 NIC (eno1, eno2, eno3, eno4). I'm trying to establish the following setup:

```
Host - Ubuntu Server 18.04 running KVM {
     VM1 - Webserver Ubuntu 16.04
     VM2 - Fileserver Ubuntu 16.04
}
```

**eno1**: Reserved for VM host access (Ubuntu Server 18.04).

**eno2 -> br0**: eno2 bridged to br0, reserved for web server.

**(eno3-eno4) -> br1**:

eno3 and eno4 bonded, in active-rr mode, later bridged to br1 for the file server.

Because the host is running on Ubuntu Server 18.04 I'm using Netplan to configure the above, here is my yaml file:

**[Edited after heynnema's comments, 3rd revision]**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [10.0.0.10/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.1]
    eno2:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: false
    eno3:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: false
    eno4:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: false

  bridges:
    br0:
      addresses: [10.0.0.11/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.1]
      interfaces: [eno2]
    br1:
      addresses: [10.0.0.12/24]
      gateway4: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.0.1]
      interfaces: [bond0]

  bonds:
    bond0:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: true
      interfaces: [eno3,eno4]
      parameters:
        mode: active-rr
```

Apply the settings:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan apply
```

ifconfig reveals:
**[Refreshed after heynnema's comments, 3rd revision]**

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 2a:0c:4e:3a:0d:ed  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 988  bytes 483252 (483.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 549  bytes 59611 (59.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 8 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet6 fe80::dcc9:e1ff:fe34:1282  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether de:c9:e1:34:12:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 149  bytes 30135 (30.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 12  bytes 936 (936.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.12  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet6 fe80::30d6:53ff:fe76:2cdf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 32:d6:53:76:2c:df  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 958  bytes 467860 (467.8 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 544  bytes 56791 (56.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.0.0.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
    inet6 fe80::1260:4bff:fea9:428  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 10:60:4b:a9:04:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 65  bytes 7278 (7.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 16  bytes 1200 (1.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xf7f00000-f7ffffff  

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 10:60:4b:a9:04:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 552  bytes 413409 (413.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 297  bytes 19294 (19.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xf7d00000-f7dfffff  

eno3: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 2a:0c:4e:3a:0d:ed  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 476  bytes 240597 (240.5 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 274  bytes 26232 (26.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xf7b00000-f7bfffff  

eno4: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 2a:0c:4e:3a:0d:ed  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 512  bytes 242655 (242.6 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 275  bytes 33379 (33.3 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device memory 0xf7900000-f79fffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 120  bytes 9408 (9.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 120  bytes 9408 (9.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 52:54:00:a4:a5:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fee0:bf1b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:54:00:e0:bf:1b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 285  bytes 18358 (18.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 506  bytes 409706 (409.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe79:4f63  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:54:00:79:4f:63  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 145  bytes 36033 (36.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Installing the first vm (webserver) works fine using **br0**, I can ssh in and my router acknowledges the domain.

The installation process on the file server using **br1** gets interrupted saying the dhcp network isn't configured correctly. When I ssh into **br1**, it connects me to the VM host. I'm not sure how to tell the host to use **eno1** and for the file installation to acknowledge **br1**.

Comment: Your .yaml file needs to start with `network:`, `version: 2`, `renderer: networkd`. Your commands should be `sudo netplan --debug generate` and `sudo netplan apply`. You've not defined any nameservers or routes.

Comment: In the final example of this link: https://www.aptgetlife.co.uk/setting-up-a-bond-and-bridge-in-netplan-on-ubuntu-18-04/ there's no declaration of a version or renderer. Does it make a difference in my case if renderer is networkd, or NetworkManager? I'll amend my file tomorrow with your suggestions and report back, thanks.

Comment: You have `version: 2` in your .yaml file, but it's in the wrong place. In your case, renderer should be networkd. Look at https://netplan.io/examples for more .yaml examples. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I've made some adjustments to what I believe to be correct. I've updated the original with the results. Same outcome: "Your network is probably not using DHCP Protocol..." I've got a feeling my Netplan file is still missing something due to my lack of knowledge of networking.

Comment: I looks better/cleaner. I suspect that the problem is in your bond0 definition. To prove this, lets change the br1 definition from `interfaces: [bond0]` to `interfaces: [en03]`, and comment out the entire bonds section. Do the generate/apply/reboot (pay attention to any error/debug messages) and see if br1 acts anywhere close to what you want. If so, we'll probably move some stuff from br1 to bond0. Also note that I'm told that netplan is very fussy about indentation... don't know it that's true... but change your 4 space indents to 2 space indents. Report back.

Comment: I have to confess, I didn't generate on the last attempt, sorry I forgot. Ok, made the suggestion amendments. Installation of the file server completed after bypassing 'bond0'. I've updated the above with the edits.

Comment: Good, we're making good progress. Now we'll try the next 1 or 2 changes, and see if we can finish the job :-) Change the br1 back to bond0 like you had before, uncomment the bonds section, and change the bond0 to `dhcp4: true`, generate/apply/reboot (again checking for generate error/debug messages) and let's see what happens.

Comment: Suggested edits made, updated above. I'm afraid it didn't work. Debugging information didn't show anything unusual.

Comment: That's ok, I wasn't sure that it would. So... attempt #2... MOVE the br1 addresses/gateway/nameservers/addresses (leaving just the interfaces) to bond0, REPLACING the addresses/dhcp4 lines. Same ritual... generate/apply/reboot.

Comment: After doing what you suggested, I can no longer SSH in through 10.0.0.10 to the host (to copy all the implementations onto here). br1 disappeared from ifconfig. Installation failed. I'm going to call it a night for now, pick this up tomorrow night before I end up single hah! Thanks for helping me, I appreciate the time your throwing at this.

Comment: That's too bad. Obviously, do your edits to back up one step to the way it was before, and maybe after a good nights sleep, we can figure out what's wrong with bond0. Cheers!

Comment: I think I just discovered why bond0 isn't working... do you have 4 separate NIC cards? I ask because I see that en03 and en04 have the SAME MAC address of 2a:0c:4e:3a:0d:ed! And so does bond0! Maybe that's the way it's supposed to look. We'll play some more with bond0 when you return.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85665/discussion-between-cworner1-and-heynnema).

Comment: I'm there :-)  I've left a brief idea for you there.

Comment: See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man5/netplan.5.html for some helpful info, and follow the "See Also" links at the bottom of that page. The **netplan try** command looks like it might help in troubleshooting. Cheers!